# amp-img not gettnig rendered inside amp-list with empty state

Tags: amp-html

I am implementing an `amp-list` containing `amp-img` with src from `amp-state`. Following is the code:

```
<amp-state id="cars" [src]="'/api/cars/?id=' + (carId || '')">
    <script type="application/json">
        []
    </script>
</amp-state>

<amp-list id="car-list" layout="fixed-height" src="cars" [src]="cars" height="0" [height]="200 * cars.length" items=".">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        <li>
            <h4 class="margin-bottom10">
                <a target="_blank" href="{{Url}}" class="carName">{{CarName}}</a>
            </h4>
            <div class="carThumb">
                <a class="imgholder" target="_blank" href="{{Url}}">
                    <amp-img layout="responsive" width="50" height="50" src="{{HostUrl}}{{^HostUrl}}https://img.cdn.com/{{/HostUrl}}300x300{{ImgPath}}{{^ImgPath}}/grey.gif{{/ImgPath}}" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </template>
</amp-list>
```

When I am setting the `carId` here, the array gets bound in `amp-state` and the list is rendered. In this list, the carName is visible, but the `amp-img` is not getting rendered (`img` tag not getting added in `amp-img`). What could be the possible reason for this?

I have tried defining the `amp-state` without empty array like following:

```
<amp-state id="cars" [src]="'/api/cars/?id=' + (carId || '')">
</amp-state>
```

In this case, image is getting rendered but I am getting following error in cosole related to `amp-list`:

```
log.js:162 New renderItems_, continuing render pass...
```

What is the cause of this error? What is the correct way to implement this?